# GPO - Missing "Manage updates offered from Windows Server Update Service"

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller, windows-server-2019, wsus

in our Windows Server 2019 DC we are missing the following Administrative Template:

Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > **Manage updates offered from Windows Server Update Service**

Is that something introduce only in Windows Server 2022 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the CIS Windows Server Benchmark:

"Note: This section was initially named Defer Windows Updates but was renamed by Microsoft to Windows Update for Business starting with the Microsoft Windows 10 Release
1709 Administrative Templates. It was renamed (again) to Manage updates offered from Windows Update starting with the Microsoft Windows 11 Release 21H2 Administrative
Templates."

Probably an existing setting/branch that was renamed.

Try downloading the latest Group Policy Administrative Templates current for Windows 11. Update the templates on the host that you are running GPMC on. By default Windows uses admx templates from the local machine. If you are using the Group Policy Central Store, you should update that location.

Using updated templates should display the settings correctly.

Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 11 2022 Update (22H2)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104593

Comment: Installed it on the PDC , (even 23H2 Update), but still can't see it. It looks like I am missing something...

Comment: Can you confirm the location of the updated files, and the location shown in GPMC?

Comment: To be honest I have simply run the MSI installer and that's all. Sorry for the "newbie question", but I thought it was enough to do that

Comment: The files need to be copied from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Group Policy\<version-specific>\PolicyDefinitions` to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`. However, that is a protected folder, so you need to take ownership of the folder and all subfolders and files, and assign Administrators full control. Then confirm in GPMC in the left pane the location shown for the policy definitions.

Comment: I am going to try it thank you very much

Comment: I have checked and we are not using a Central Store. We use plain standard GPO in a Windows Server 2019 Domain. Do I need to use a Central Store ?

Comment: No, Central Store not required.